# Catching mysql output in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to write a shell script in which i can run mysql commands after reading from the file. I have to capture the output of the sql commands in a separate file. Following is the code :

```
mysql -h ${DB_SERVER} -P ${DB_PORT} -u ${USER} -p${PASS} -f < createUsers.sql >> install.log
```

Shell script takes a few inputs from the user.
When i run the shell script and if i specify a wrong password, the error shows up on the console but not in the log file.

Please suggest how can i redirect the error to the log file as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `2>&1` on to the end to also capture stderr. Standard out is file descriptor 1 and standard error is 2, so this redirects stderr to wherever stdout 1 is going, i.e. install.log.

```
mysql [options] < createUsers.sql >> install.log 2>&1
```

Note: The order of redirections matters. Make sure you put it *after* the `>>`, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

When running MySQL commands in a batch file I wasn't able to use the: `%logfile% 2>&1` command because it would log *everything* that MySQL was doing, and I ended up with log files the same size as my backup files (nearly 500mb).  Not very useful.

Instead I used `2>> %logfile%` which will only log errors to my log file.

```
set tempFile1=dropAndCreate.txt
echo DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS %testDatabase%; > %tempFile1%
echo CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %testDatabase%; >> %tempFile1%
mysqldump -e -u %user% -p%pwd% %productionDatabase% > %backupFile% 2>> %logFile%
mysql -u %user% -p%pwd% < %tempFile1% 2>> %logFile%
mysqldump -u %user% -p%pwd% %productionDatabase% | mysql -u %user% -p%pwd% %testDatabase% 2>> %logFile%
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 #!/bin/sh

./mysql -u<user_name> -p<password>  database_name  < db.sql  > output.txt

**#db.sql contains all mysql queries(input file),output is redirected to output.txt.
# # replace user name and password fields with appropriate name and password
# # this works provided your working directory and mysql directory are same otherwise provide required directories to    input #file and output file
# # otherwise it throws an error "no file or directory"
# #whatever db.sql output is ,it will be in output.txt**
```